# replace popup window print to jspdf

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jspdf

Hi I have this code when click, there's a popup window and download pdf.
There's a lot of issue first, when I close and click it again, it's not opening anymore, second, I want to download it directly to pdf by not popping any window. So I'm thinking is it possible to add JSPDF for this so I can download it directly? Thanks!

Here's my code

```
var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;       
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;     
window.print();      
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
setTimeout(function () { window.close(); }, 100);
```

Comment: You are printing/saving `document.body` ? Is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: yes. I will hide the other elements through print.css

Comment: Is this fiddle good? https://jsfiddle.net/hbyhssLh/

Comment: Thank you! @AmreshVenugopal can you help me also to download it directly as PDF?

Comment: Sure, I'll check some native way of doing it.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution using `window.print()`

To print using `window.print()` you can refer to this snippet.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('click');

button.onclick = function () {
  window.print();
}
```

```html
Today is a good day! 
<button id='click'> Click me! </button>
```

## The Problem

The reason why it wasn't working is this part of your code where you explicitly reassign the `body`.

```
document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;     
originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Which would be proven by this:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('click');

button.onclick = function () {
  console.log('Can you see me?');
  var contents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = contents;
}
```

```html
<button id='click'>click me<button>
```

It won't console more than once.

## Using jsPDF

You can replace the pop up and use jsPDF library like so:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('click');

button.onclick = function () {
 var doc = new jsPDF();
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  doc.text(originalContents, 10, 10);
 doc.save();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
Today is a good day! 
<button id='click'> Click me! </button>
```